# How do I enforce field type when saving through POST in MongoDB and Node.js? Aka, how to create a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to produce a 'catch-all' update POST query for my application.

Basically I need to perform the POST request with an identifier ID and fields to update, and it would update those fields dynamically. Here's what I have so far (in CoffeeScript):

```
router.post '/update', (req, res) ->
  whitelist = ['name', 'price', 'quantity', 'checked']
  toUpdate = {}
  for attr, val of req.body
    if attr in whitelist
      toUpdate[attr] = val

  if toUpdate.length > 0
    (req.db.collection 'products').findAndModify {
      query: {_id: req.body.id}
      update: {$set: toUpdate}
    }
```

Problem is, I can only pass it strings.

For example, if I wanna update a boolean, I don't know how to enforce the correct type.

POST request:

```
{ checked: 'true' }
```

Which will save like so in the database, but what I WANT to have is:

```
{ checked: true }
```

So my question is, is there a way to automatically enforce the correct type, so that it will convert by a set of rules I define per field?

Or do I have to code this manually before saving?

I tried looking up creating models in MongoDB, but it's really a big mess, I can't understand anything from the documentation. Google isn't coming up with good results either because I can't really seem to phrase what I want correctly in a search query.

Comment: Add an if statement ? `toUpdate['field'] = toUpdate['field'] == 'true' ? true : false`

Comment: @KevinLabécot So my question is do I have to do that every time I manipulate some field, or can I enforce it globally through a model of some sorts?

Comment: You want an ODM or Object Document Mapper "mongodb ODM nodejs" ( which google will actually autocorrect from asking ORM ) actually returns the number 1 solution used as the top result. Funny that. MongoDB is "schemaless" so any definition of schema is done application side.

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried using Mongoose before and it seemed like an overkill and a bit complex, but I guess if it's inevitable I'll give it another go. Thanks

Comment: We generally try to comment before you receive silly "link only" answers like, well what has just happened. You would have been better of posting your mongoose "how to do question". But MongoDB does not do this itself, and it does so deliberately.